# Why doesn't my ALL operator work in this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going through W3school's SQL tutorial, and they have an example here with the ALL operator.

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ALL (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

I interpreted this as "Return the product name if every instance of its product ID has a quantity of 10 in Order Details." It returns 0 records, because every product had at least one order where it was ordered in a quantity other than 10.

So I wanted to see a positive example. I found that the max quantity of any item in a shipment was 120.

```
SELECT Max(Quantity) FROM OrderDetails;"
```

I then modified the original statement to say:

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ALL (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity < 1000);
```

So here I thought I was trying to say "Return the product name if every instance of its product ID has a quantity of less than 1000 in Order Details," which would surely be every product, since the max quantity was 120. But I still got 0 records. Can anyone explain what was wrong with my syntax/interpretation?

The SQL simulator that's linked to the tables can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all2&ss=-1

Comment: "SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);"

Can you try this query please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns a product if all instances sold in quantity equal to 10 are this particular product. In other words, the product would be in the result only if there is no other product sold in quantity equal to 10. To return what you need you have to change it slightly:

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products p
WHERE 10 = ALL (SELECT Quantity 
                FROM OrderDetails 
                WHERE OrderDetails.ProductID  = Products.ProductID  );
```

There are also other ways to solve it using `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM OrderDetails 
                WHERE OrderDetails.ProductID  = Products.ProductID AND
                      OrderDetails.Quantity != 10);
```

Comment: @NicholasHassan no, you wanted to return the product if the product was the only product sold in 10 quantity.

Comment: Ah interesting! So to use the same phrasing as my original post, what I was actually saying was: "Return the product name if all the instances of quantity = 10 are of its product ID."
And similarly, my second syntax was saying "Return the product name if all the instances of quantity < 1000 are of its product ID."
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`= All` doesn't mean what you think it means. `column = All(subquery)` is equivalent to `NOT( column NOT IN (subquery) ) AND COUNT(subquery) > 0`

The left hand side is a single value, the right hand side is a result set. It is true when the single value is equal to every value in the result set, and the result set is non-empty.

Your subquery `SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity < 1000` returns more than 1 unique value, so an `= All` expression with it on the right hand side is never true. Because `SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10` has only one result, it is true for `ProductID` 42, which is not in the example Products