# Using ALL in SQL example on w3schools site

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL and now studying w3schools tutorial. I guess their example on ALL keyword is incorrect, but may be I just don't understand it. This is it

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ALL (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

Explanation for this code is

> The following SQL statement returns TRUE and lists the productnames if
>   ALL the records in the OrderDetails table has quantity = 10

As I understand, SELECT returns us all products ID that has orders with quantity equals to 10, so we have list of ID. Then we apply our ALL operator but ID can't equal to all ID simultaneously so we got empty list. It's how I understand it.

I have tried to report error on their site, but haven't received any answer.
Please help me to understand this.

Edit: RDBMS is not specified, so it is supposed to work in all I guess. Here is link to example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_all.asp

Comment: Do they specify what RDBMS their SQL is supposed to work with?

Comment: The same question for the same code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540407/why-doesnt-my-all-operator-work-in-this-sql-statement

Comment: @forpas, oh, thanks, I could not find this question. May be I should delete my.

Comment: I guess, if you think the answers there are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is almost correct.  And the explanation on the site is just bogus.

However, the query will return:

- The one `productname` if there is exactly one `productid` with a `quantity` of 10.
- All the `productname`s if there are no `productid`s with a quantity of 10.

(This assumes that `ProductId` is unique in `products`, which is a reasonable assumption.)

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb01e0893f52e6e9e78e9e1f66270773) is a db<>fiddle illustrating this.

It is easy to forget that `ALL` also applies to an empty list.  So, any given `ProductId` is equal to all the `ProductId`s in an empty list -- even a `NULL` `ProductId`.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement here is essentially correct:

> SELECT returns us all products ID that has orders with quantity equals
>   to 10, so we have list of ID. Then we apply our ALL operator but ID
>   can't equal to all ID simultaneously so we got empty list.

The one exception to the second sentence is that, if the subquery returns only one row, then the `ALL` is irrelevant and a single product should be returned.

As far as I can tell, what the tutorial says about this statement is nonsense, unless there is some RDBMS I am not familiar with that handles this syntax differently (i.e. incorrectly).

Aside from their description of the `ALL` behavior, the statement "The following SQL statement returns TRUE" is nonsense.  SQL statements don't return TRUE or FALSE. They return rows.